# Is there something similar to WebClient.DownloadString in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, webclient

I want to download the html source code of a site to parse some info. How do I accomplish this in Java?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just attach a BufferedReader (or anything that reads strings) from a URL's InputStream returned from openStream().

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException
{
    URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

    String s = null;
    while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, do not forget to close reader `try (BufferedReader reader ... )) { }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Java classes directly:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
...
```

but it's more recommended to use [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) as HttpClient will handle a lot of things that you'll have to do yourself with the Java native classes.