# Read a file stored on a raspberry pi from an android application

Tags: java, android, raspberry-pi

I'm currently working on developing an android application that needs to connect to a Raspberry Pi over a local WiFi connection and read some data from a file stored on the RPi. I'm not really sure where to begin on this and what resources I can use. I already have the layout of the application set up and just need to write the code.

So my question is how should I write the android application to read a file from a Raspberry Pi that is connected to a local WiFi network? The file on the Pi could be either a JSON file or a plain text file.

Comment: You have 3 people who were kind enough to give you some sound guidance on things you can research to get you started.  You should do some google searches now, and ACTUALLY TRY SOMETHING.  StackOverflow is to assist people with programming problems. You don't even have a problem yet, you just have an idea you haven't put enough time into researching yet.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what you guys are suggesting. I understand that I need to put some sort of server software on the Pi. But I don't understand how to access it from android. Thanks for the vote of confidence.

Comment: I went to google, typed in "read a text file from android from a web server" and I got this StackOverflow page with the answer right on top: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922210/reading-text-file-from-server-on-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Host the files [with Apache](https://askubuntu.com/questions/388611/how-do-i-create-public-html-folder), and then download them with [WebClient.DownloadString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring(v=vs.110).aspx)

**EDIT:** For Android, look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098606/is-there-something-similar-to-webclient-downloadstring-in-java)

Comment: Or, install Samba on the raspberry and refer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389366/how-to-access-share-folder-in-windows-through-android-and-read-files)

Comment: How do I download them with WebClient.DownloadString if that is made for .NET? I'm working with Java.

Comment: @schilling399 Look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098606/is-there-something-similar-to-webclient-downloadstring-in-java

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This will get me started in the right direction.

Comment: WebClient.DownloadString is for .NET, it's off-topic to this Android question.  (Unless you're using Xamarin)

Answer (score 2):

For your case, I'd say stop thinking about it as a Raspberry Pi.  My guess is that you're going to put NOOBS\Raspberian on it.  At that point, it's a linux server.

You can put Apache on it, or an FTP server, or do some google searches on accessing a linux server from android to see a variety of different design patterns that accomplish this task.

Comment: I do have Raspbian on the Pi. Isn't Apache a DB? I just need simple text or JSON file to be read into my Android application.

Comment: @schilling399 For the record Apache isn't a database, it's a server application used to host files.